# Redis cluster creation

Tags: redis

Is it possible to create a redis cluster with 2 nodes , one acting as a master and other one as slave.

I get the following error if I try with 2 nodes (one as master and other as slave)

```
>>> Creating cluster
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:6379: OK
Connecting to node 192.168.40.159:6379: OK
*** ERROR: Invalid configuration for cluster creation.
*** Redis Cluster requires at least 3 master nodes.
*** This is not possible with 2 nodes and 1 replicas per node.
*** At least 6 nodes are required.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. Redis Cluster is still in beta. Redis Replication has been there for years, and has had a huge update in 2.8.4 with various improvements. For 1 master and 1 slave you only need replication. Simply do a 'slave of' in the slave and you are set.

Comment: The best tutorial on Redis cluster setup: http://codeflex.co/configuring-redis-cluster-on-linux/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. The requirement of at least 3 master nodes is set by the ruby script, but not a hard limit in cluster.

The first thing you need to do is send a `cluster` command with 16385 arguments like

```
cluster addslots 0 1 2 3 ... 16384
```

to the cluster. Since there is too many arguments to manually type them in a redis-cli, I suggest write a program to do that, in which you open a TCP socket connecting to the redis node, convert the previous command into a redis command string and write it to the socket.

The single node cluster will be online after few seconds you send the command. Then connect to the other node with redis-cli, type the following command to make it a slave

```
cluster meet MASTER_HOST MASTER_PORT
cluster replicate MASTER_ID
```

where `MASTER_HOST:MASTER_PORT` is the address of the previous node, and `MASTER_ID` is the ID of that node, which you could retrieve it via a `cluster nodes` command.

For convenience I've written a python tool for those kinds of redis cluster management, you could install it with

```
pip install redis-trib
```

For more detail please go to https://github.com/HunanTV/redis-trib.py/

Answer (score 2):

Redis-Cluster is not a fit for your use case.

For your use case, you need to configure one server (the master), then configure a second server and add the "slaveof" directive - pointing it to the master. How you handle failover is up to your scenario but I would recommend the use of redis-sentinel.

For a more detailed walkthrough, see the [Redis Replication page](http://redis.io/topics/replication)

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it is not possible to create a redis cluster with 1 master node, as suggested [here](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial#creating-and-using-a-redis-cluster) setting up a redis cluster requires atleast 3 master nodes.

Answer (score 0):

'redis-trib.rb create' command requires at least 3 nodes.
this way can make 1 master, 1 slave redis cluster.

### Using redis-trib

$ redis-server 5001/redis.conf
$ redis-trib.rb fix 127.0.0.1:5001
so many messages ...

$ redis-server 5002/redis.conf
$ redis-trib.rb add-node --slave 127.0.0.1:5002 127.0.0.1:5001

```
>>> Adding node 127.0.0.1:5002 to cluster 127.0.0.1:5001<br>
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:5001: OK<br>
>>> Performing Cluster Check (using node 127.0.0.1:5001)<br>
M: 015bec64d631990b83ad63736d906cda257a762c 127.0.0.1:5001<br>
   slots:0-16383 (16384 slots) master<br>
   0 additional replica(s)<br>
[OK] All nodes agree about slots configuration.<br>
>>> Check for open slots...<br>
>>> Check slots coverage...<br>
[OK] All 16384 slots covered.<br>
Automatically selected master 127.0.0.1:5001<br>
Connecting to node 127.0.0.1:5002: OK<br>
>>> Send CLUSTER MEET to node 127.0.0.1:5002 to make it join the cluster.<br>
Waiting for the cluster to join.<br>
>>> Configure node as replica of 127.0.0.1:5001.<br>
[OK] New node added correctly.
```

### Using cluster commands

$ redis-server 5001/redis.conf

Using Ruby : addslots
$ echo '(0..16383).each{|x| puts "cluster addslots "+x.to_s}' | ruby | redis-cli -c -p 5001 > /dev/null

$ redis-server 5002/redis.conf
$ redis-cli -c -p 5002
127.0.0.1:5002> cluster meet 127.0.0.1 5001
OK
127.0.0.1:5002> cluster replicate 7c38d2e5e76fc4857fe238e34b4096fc9c9f12a5 
 *node-id of 5001*
OK